# How to create a JPanel inside a Jframe?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I have a class that extends JFrame that has a menubar and menu Items inside of it. Under the menu bar I want to add a JPanel where I can add components and draw shapes.How would I add a JPanel inside of this class? Sorry if this is an easy question I am a beginner.

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.*;

public class theMenu extends JFrame {

  static JMenuBar menubar;
    JMenu shape, color;
    JCheckBox fill;
    JButton btn1,btn2;
    JMenuItem circle, rectangle, line,triangle;
    JMenuItem red, green, blue, yellow;

 public theMenu(){
  super("Using JMenus");     
  menubar=new JMenuBar ();
  shape=new JMenu ("Shape");
  add(menubar);
  setJMenuBar(menubar); // add menu bar to application
  shape=new JMenu ("Shape");
  color=new JMenu ("Color");
  fill=new JCheckBox("fill");
  btn1=new JButton("save");
  btn2=new JButton("import");
  circle=new JMenuItem ("Circle");
  rectangle=new JMenuItem ("Rectangle");
  line=new JMenuItem ("Line");
  triangle = new JMenuItem ("Triangle");
  red=new JMenuItem ("Red");
  green=new JMenuItem ("Green");
  blue=new JMenuItem ("Blue");
  yellow=new JMenuItem ("Yellow");

  shape.add (circle);
  shape.add (rectangle);
  shape.add (line);
  shape.add (triangle);

  color.add (red);
  color.add (green);
  color.add (blue);
  color.add (yellow);

  menubar.add (shape);
  menubar.add(color);
  menubar.add(fill);
  menubar.add(btn1);
  menubar.add(btn2);
 }
}
```

Comment: same principle as you are doing so far....

Comment: the fast way is use gui builder in netbeans or eclipse

Comment: Beyond that: read about java naming conventions. Class names go CamelCase. Always.

Answer (score 4):

Simple:

- you create a panel
- you add it to the frame

Like:

```
JPanel p = new JPanel(); 
f.getContentPane().add(p);
```

For more information, start reading [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html).

Beyond that: you should **first** read about the difference between static and non-static fields. It is simply bad practice to have **all** static fields (shared between instances of your class); and to then use those as "normal" fields within your constructor.

In other words: you might want to study the *basics* of Java first, before writing Swing UI applications. Swing shouldn't be your "first stop" when looking for examples to learn about Java. And if you still want to start with Java - then take **existing** tutorials - "trial and error" isn't an efficient strategy to learn a framework such as Swing. There are many subtle details you have to know about - not knowing them translates to: running from one problem to the next.